# Flutter, can't turn int to string for displaying text on the screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have a feeling that more than one thing is wrong with my code, but I'm attempting to display a set of `int` into the screen, only that it won't turn them into a string. please look at my code and try to help. I want '`_result = ('$z+$y+$x+$w+$v') as int;`' to be displayed on the app screen but when using `String resultS = _result.toString();` I get the **"The instance member '_result' can't be accessed in an initializer."** so when I try to initialization into a constructor like so

```
   int _result = 0;
      
      MyApp (){
        String resultS = _result.toString();

  }
```

then String **resultS** gets grayed out and won't allow to use `child: Text('$resultS'),` in the last container. what do I do wrong?

Here's the full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  var sum = 25;

  int _result = 0;
  String resultS = _result.toString();

  void callForLoop() {
    print('The sum of ' '$sum' ' with 5 digits');
    for (int z = 1; z <= 9; z++) {
      for (int y = 1; y <= 9; y++) {
        for (int x = 1; x <= 9; x++) {
          for (int w = 1; w <= 9; w++) {
            for (int v = 1; v <= 9; v++) {
              if (z + y + x + w + v == sum) {
                if (z < y) {
                  if (y < x) {
                    if (x < w) {
                      if (w < v) {
                        _result = ('$z+$y+$x+$w+$v') as int;
                        continue;
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => callForLoop(),
                child: Text('Call For Loop'),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                color: Colors.lightBlue,
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 12, 12),
              )),
          Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text('$resultS'),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                color: Colors.black87,
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 12, 12),
              )),
        ]))));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you can't do this. Declaring and using it at same time, you have to make it `const`.
If want to deploy at class level make it `static` like

```
static const int _result = 0;
String resultS = _result.toString();
```

inside build method, you just need to make it `const`

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  const int _result = 0;
  String resultS = _result.toString();
```

Comment: It appears to be correct on the code when I made these changes but when I try to run it I get this: "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' in typecast"

Comment: then use tryParse